# How do I get angular 10 to error on unknown binding?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

Example component:

```
@Component({ selector: "person" })
export class PersonComponent {
  @Input() age: number;
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

Example usage:

```
<person [age]="55" [naame]="'John'"></person>
```

Is it possible to make angular error because (1) I did not provide a value for the input `name` and (2) because I am binding to a property `naame` that does not exists?

My `tsconfig.json` contains the following but it does not seem enough.

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true
  }
```

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but in my current angular 13 project running in webstorm, this works out of the box.

Comment: If I need to just upgrade to latest version then that's what I'll do. Might not be supported in ng10.

Comment: That’s possible, I’m not sure. Unless it is related to your IDE?

Comment: Do you want it to error in an editor, during the build, or in the browser at runtime?

Comment: Anywhere. But I tend to look at all the errors during the build.